# Is there any Vaishnava commentary on Manu-Smriti?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, manu-smriti, gaudiya-vaishnavism, translation

I have seen few commentaries (and even fewer translations in English) of the Manu Samhita.

But I can't find any done by a Vaishnava (no regards to the sampradaya).

Thus I'm wondering is it because simply none was done or was famous enough to have survived time?